# DatePicker height blinks when presented in .fullScreenCover(_ :) - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, datepicker

[image: Click to view the issue]

I'm trying to present a view with the **DatePicker** in it. When the view is presented suddenly the DatePicker height increases with a blink.

`Working on min iOS version 14`

Here is the code,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showDatePicker : Bool = false
    @State private var pickedDate : Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                showDatePicker.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Show Date Picker")
            }

            
            Spacer()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDatePicker) {
            DatePicker("Date Picker",
                       selection: $pickedDate,
                       displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

When normally doing hide/show in a view by a flag it works fine. The blink appears when presenting with `.fullScreenCover(_:)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one is Working.

**Xcode:** 14.3 **iOS Target:** 16.2

```
@State private var showDatePicker : Bool = false
@State private var pickedDate = Date()
    
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Spacer()
        Button {
            showDatePicker.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Show Date Picker")
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDatePicker) {
        DatePicker("Date Picker",
                   selection: $pickedDate,
                   displayedComponents: [.date])
        .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .onAppear{
            self.pickedDate = Date()
        }
    }
}
```